# Cannot find resource for the request AppTiles

Tags: office-365, rest, odata

I am working with Office 365 and using below service to get details of all AppTiles

```
https://<site>/_api/Web/AppTiles
```

So to get details of specific tile i am using below url

```
https://<site>/_api/Web/AppTiles(guid'AppId')
```

which gives me below error message

> *Cannot find resource for the request AppTiles.*

Am I using correct url to get details of AppTile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no end-point like `https://<site>/_api/Web/AppTiles(guid'AppId')`. That's why you are getting following error.

> Cannot find resource for the request AppTiles.

So now you can consider using `$filter`. It will do the same thing.

```
 https://<site>/_api/Web/AppTiles?$filter=AppId eq guid'{guid of app id}'
```